# Git - head (lowercase) vs HEAD (uppercase)

Tags: git

Did I understand correct and the difference between Git head (lowercase) and Git HEAD (uppercase) is that the former is the **end commit** and the latter is just the **current commit** (whether an end-commit or a non-end commit chosen to be the HEAD commit)?

Edit: By "end-commit" I meant to "last commit of a given branch".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the command line of `git` you write:

`HEAD` is the current commit, that is the commit that is currently checkout out in the working directoy.

`head`, as is, means nothing for GIT, unless you have a branch or a tag named `head`. But that sounds like a bad idea.

But when the documentation talks about the *head* of a branch it refers to the last commit of that branch, maybe that is what you mean with *end commit*. In real commands you will use the name of the branch, such as `master` (or `origin/master` for the remote head), not the literal word `head`.

Comment: I agree with what you said, and from what I read `head` (lowercase) has no special semantic meaning in Git, but it _does_ have a usage, to refer to any head in a repository.  But I don't think the OP is wrong per se.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I see your point. I assumed the OP was using `head` in the command line, but maybe they are only asking about the general meaning of `HEAD` vs _head_. I've rephrased the answer a bit.

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen `head` being used in Git in the 6+ years I have been using it.  I think it has a semantic meaning, but is not part of a verbatim command.   Anyway, +1 to your answer, which I almost posted similarly myself.

Comment: I'd like to add that `HEAD` is case insensitive on Windows, which could be the source of confusion.

Comment: Indeed, @rodrigo by "end-commit" I meant to last commit of a given branch.

Comment: Would thumb up the answer if I could - very didactic, thanks!

Comment: This is incorrect, i'm not sure about past git versions but in current ones you can use `head` in any place you'd use `HEAD`

Comment: @horseyguy Not really. `HEAD` is actually a file in the `.git` directory, so I'm guessing that you are using Windows, where the filesystem is case insensitive. In a proper, case-insensitive, filesystem `git show head` shows nothing.

Comment: @rodrigo no i'm using a modern version of git on osx git version 2.14.3, and it actually supports: `git show hEad` and so on too. They all seem to 'just work' on my git version on osx.

Comment: @horseguy Well, as it seems, HFS+ is case insensitive, too... ugh!

Comment: @rodrigo haha you're right! i had no idea HFS+ was case insensitive!! Jesus christ, i'm in shock. Sorry, you were right all along.

Answer (score 20):

It's worth mentioning that when you're on a case-insensitive file system—as is the default on Windows and MacOS, for instance—that trying to open the file `abc` will open instead the existing file `ABC`, if it indeed exists, and of course vice versa.

Git stores information *about* the current commit in a file.  For most cases, that file is named `.git/HEAD`.  So when Git tries to access information about the current commit, it just opens `.git/HEAD` and reads it.  (The file usually contains the *name of the current branch*.  For instance, if you're on your `master` branch, your `.git/HEAD` file will read: `ref: refs/heads/master`.)

For instance, when you run `git show` with no addition arguments, Git reads `.git/HEAD` to find out that you're on `master`, then reads either `.git/packed-refs` or `.git/refs/heads/master` to find out which commit `master` means, and shows that commit.  **All of these are implementation details that might change in the future, and some of these *do* change in modern Git under some circumstances, so it's not wise to *depend* on this.**  But that's how it actually works today.

If you run `git show xyz`, Git tries to find `.git/refs/heads/xyz` and, if that doesn't work, tries to find `.git/packed-refs` to see if there's a line in it about branch `xyz`.  Git also tries to find `.git/refs/tags/xyz`, and `.git/xyz`.  The precise order in which Git tries each of these operations is another implementation detail, but is actually documented—after a fashion; the documentation describes the *result* rather than the method—in [the gitrevisions manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

If you run `git show head`, and you're on Windows or MacOS, Git eventually tries to open `.git/head`.  Since your operating system is willing to treat that as a request to open, instead, `.git/HEAD`, and since `.git/HEAD` *does* actually exist, your OS opens `.git/HEAD`.  Git reads `ref: refs/heads/master` (or whatever) out of that file, and shows you the same commit you would have seen if you had run `git show HEAD` or just plain `git show`.

Where this goes wrong, in modern Git, is when you're in an *added* work-tree, one constructed by running `git worktree add ...`.  The `HEAD` of an *added* work-tree is *not* in `.git/HEAD`.  It's in another subdirectory of `.git`.  If you run `git show HEAD` in this added work-tree, Git itself sees the special name `HEAD` in all-capital-letters and knows to look up the *right* `HEAD`, the one for *this* work-tree.  But if you run `git show head`, Git *doesn't* see all-uppercase-`HEAD`, and goes on to try to open various files, starting with `.git/head`.  If this *succeeds*—if it opens `.git/HEAD`—Git reads the branch for the *main* work-tree, and not the branch for the work-tree you're actually on in the added work-tree.  So `git show HEAD`, in the added work-tree, shows the current commit there; but `git show head`, in this same added work-tree, shows the current commit of the main work-tree, rather than this one.

On Linux, using the usual file systems (which are case-sensitive), `git show head` just doesn't work at all.  Avoid this bad habit: if you don't like typing `HEAD` in all uppercase, use `@`.

Comment: Before using worktree, I was using `head`. Unfortunately now that I'm using worktree, I experience accidental issue when doing `git reset head~` for example because it reset to the previous commit of the main worktree which turns to be bad when I'm in another worktree. Is there a way to either alias `head` to the current worktree HEAD of prevent its usage ?

Answer (score 1):

From what i examined, 'head' and 'HEAD' are the same, both could be used to refer to the current checked out commit.

You can checkout any commit of a branch and use `git show` command to examine the commit hash value.

`git show head` and `git show HEAD` will display the same commit, which is the current commit.

Comment: This appears to depend on the environment. I tried this in Windows 10 (NTFS) with git version 2.17.0 and case alternatives to `HEAD` like `hEAD` returned the branch for the *primary* worktree instead of the current worktree in a multi-worktree environment (which is another interesting edge case). On CentOS 7 (XFS) with git version 2.16.5 alternative versions of `HEAD` return `fatal: ambiguous argument 'hEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree`. Long story short, just use `HEAD`.