# git checkout HEAD vs git checkout head

Tags: git, git-checkout

Git version: 2.21.0.windows.1

Environment: mintty bash

---

**Edited:** Note this is not the exactly the same question than (IMHO): 
[Git - head (lowercase) vs HEAD (uppercase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137927/git-head-lowercase-vs-head-uppercase)

Because I am not asking for a 'concept' but a behavior of `git checkout head` and `git checkout HEAD`, doing different things.

But reading all answers, the last one reveals the right answer for my question.  Anyway, it is a strange behavior mixing `checkout+head/HEAD`.

---

**Original question text**:

Why this commands are different?

If I write head/HEAD both of them do close things but really different:

```
git checkout HEAD
```

than

```
git checkout head
```

The first one takes me to the same "place" where I am. If I am in master branch, it does nothing (it takes me to the same place).

But with the second one (head lowercase) it takes me to the commit (detached HEAD) where I am already located.
If I am in the master branch, it puts me in the same commit but in detached head.

I cannot find anything in documentation pointing this out.

Comment: Is it really duplicate @tim ?

Note I am speaking about use head/HEAD combining with `git checkout`. If you try both of them (on windows at least) you get different behavior.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate.  `head` (lowercase) doesn't have any special semantic meaning, unlike `HEAD`.